# Vectorizing multiple for loops in Matlab/Python

Tags: matlab, performance, vectorization

I am trying to code a mathematical model, and it involves computing a particular quantity over a grid of values thousands of times, with some changing model parameters. Currently, this is far too slow and I am looking for advice on vectorizing the most intensive part of my model.

I've currently got a basic implementation of it for ease of reading, but now want to vectorize the entire code segment below if possible. A minimal example of the code segment is:

```matlab
% Setup grid to evaluate and results vector
T_max = 10000;
eval_points = linspace(0, T_max, 1000);
results = zeros(size(eval_points));
% Function that is used in computation
Z_func = @(x, omega) (1./(omega.*sqrt(2*pi))).*exp( -(x.^2)./(2.*omega.*omega) );
% Random data for now, known in full problem
historic_weights = rand(1,100);
historic_times   = rand(1,100);
% Fixed single parameter omega
omega            = 0.5;
% Time evaluation
tic()
for eval_counter = 1:size(eval_points,2)
    for historic_counter = 1:size(historic_weights,2)
    temp_result = 0;
        for k = 0:1:T_max
            temp_result = temp_result + Z_func( eval_points(eval_counter) - historic_times(historic_counter) + 1440*floor(historic_times(historic_counter)/1440) - 1440*k, omega );
        end % End of looping over k
        results(eval_counter) = results(eval_counter) + historic_weights(historic_counter)*temp_result;
    end % End of looping over weights 
end % End of looping over evaluation points
toc()
```

On my computer, this took just over 60 seconds to evaluate. I do not wish to use the parallel toolbox, as I am already using that elsewhere, and the shown segment of code is called on every process.

If this is not possible in Matlab, I'm happy to also try in python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fairly easily vectorise the inner two loops by computing `temp_result` and `result` as matrices instead of one at a time. For instance:

```matlab
for eval_counter = 1:size(eval_points,2)
    temp_result = sum(Z_func( eval_points(eval_counter) - historic_times + 1440*floor(historic_times/1440) - 1440*(0:1:T_max)', omega ));
    results(eval_counter) = results(eval_counter) + sum(historic_weights.*temp_result);
end % End of looping over evaluation points
```

This runs in ~9 seconds on my machine, compared to 73 seconds for your looped version.

Now, in theory you can do this without a single loop, as follows:

```matlab
eval_points = linspace(0,T_max,1000);
historic_weights = rand(100,1); % Note transposed from original
historic_times   = rand(100,1);
eval_loop = reshape(0:T_max,1,1,[]); % size = [1,1,10000];

result = sum(historic_weight.*sum(Z_func(eval_points - historic_times + 1440*floor(historic_times/1440) - 1440*eval_loop, omega ),3),1);
```

However this will use a *significant* amount of memory (>8 GB), and so may not be feasible for your current situation. I don't have sufficient memory on my current machine to test this, so I don't know how much faster this would run, but in theory it should be even faster, due to the lack of any for-loops in the code.

Comment: The first set of code runs in ~3 seconds on my machine, a huge improvement already. I do have access to hundreds of GB of RAM, so I tried the second code, but on the result = line I get an error 'Matrix dimensions must agree.' Do you have any idea if something should be transposed and should not be?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I had forgotten to replace `(0:1:T_max)'` with `eval_loop`. I've fixed it, and it should work now.

Comment: Did you check for equivalent results? If I run the original script against your first solution for `T_max = 10` and `eval_points = linspace(0, T_max, 10)`, the two `results` differ (quite heavily). Maybe, I'm doing something wrong - that's why I'm asking if you could reproduce the original results!?

Comment: I will double check.

Comment: Testing now, they do seem to give different values for any choice of T_Max

Comment: There was actually a typo in my original code, the variable temp_result was not set to 0 before each loop over k. MrAzzaman's answer was actually the correct, both vectorized and fixing this typo. I've changed the question to reflect this now

Comment: Oh! Good spotting. I was driving myself a bit batty trying to figure out why my results were producing different results and didn't even notice that.

Comment: @Kieran108 Ha, you're right. Actually, I had the same solution as presented here, and couldn't find the mistake myself either.